# Getting system Error while Adding product into the cart -- Magento

Tags: php, session, magento, shopping-cart, system-error

Customer gets System Error while adding a product into the cart.
I think thats the session issue because when customer logs out and signs back No more "system error" appears on browser.
Here is the screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/7HmL1rtQvvs

this issue only happens after using a specific payment method.

Note: we are using Magento

Thank you all

Comment: This screenshot is faaar away from being debuggable. Have a look in the exception.log and into the reports. Have a look into the apache and php error_log.

Comment: That's because you have something wrong in the method `addAction()` at `Mage/Core/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`. Please check your apache error log and post it here.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta But It doesn't happen if we select another payment method, I happens with only one payment method not all of them

Comment: Is that you custom payment method? Have you rewrote `addAction()` of cart controller?

Comment: @KalpeshMehta Yes sir its custom payment method, No I haven't rewrote addAction() of cart controller would you elaborate more how we can do that?

Comment: check your server error.log (if apache2, /var/log/apache2/error.log) and magento error log (var/log/system.log) for better idea of the error.

Comment: @user1572306 One more thing, how can you add a product into cart AFTER using payment method?? Payment method is used in the last step.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta I mean when Customers purchased an item and gets back to the website again and try to purchase another thing. 
Like: "continue shopping" button after getting to successful page for purchasing.

Comment: @user1572306, StackOverflow is now asking me to avoid big discussions in comments :D You don't have enough reputation to chat here else we could have do that. Can u email me at k@lpe.sh, we can talk over there to resolve ur problem.

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen after adding a product to the cart or selecting a payment method?

Comment: this is a comment and not a answer.

Comment: It only happens after checking out, and try to add an item to the shopping cart again.

Comment: @Nate, I have given you +1, now you can easily comment anywhere! :)

Comment: Thank you. I really do appreciate it.